# Rounded Corners via Circle that leaves a trace

Tags: rounded-corners

In the following code, the edges do not align very well. I would like to have rounded corners. Imagine a black circle with the thickness of the line, leaving behind a trace, where the center of that circle follows the specified path. Does someone know a solution?

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    
    \begin{document}
         \begin{tikzpicture}
              \coordinate (000) at (0, 0, 0);
              \coordinate (001) at (0, 0, -1);
              \coordinate (010) at (0, 1, 0);
              \coordinate (011) at (0, 1, -1);
              \coordinate (100) at (1, 0, 0);
              \coordinate (101) at (1, 0, -1);
              \coordinate (110) at (1, 1, 0);
              \coordinate (111) at (1, 1, -1);
    
              \draw[thick, line cap = round, rounded corners = 0.8pt] (100) -- (000) -- (111) -- (100) -- (101) -- (111);
          \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community.